# Show that the radius of convergence of $e^x$ is infinite

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

I am a bit confused as to whether I am doing this question correctly.

Firstly, we have defined the radius of convergence of a power series centered at a $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x-a)^n$$

to be the positive real number $R$ such that the power series **converges uniformly** on the interval $(a-R,a+R)$ and for $x \lt a - R$, $x \gt a + R$, the series does not converge.

So, we must show that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $e^x$ centered at 0 is infinite. Initially, I answered showing it converged using the ratio test, however, I believe this is wrong as it would only show that the series converges, not necessarily uniformly, correct?

I was wondering if it would be correct to show that for the series $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n!}$ that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges absolutely and uniformly on the bounded interval $(-a,a)$ for any $a \in \Bbb{R}$ using the Weierstrasse M-test (by taking $M_n = \frac{a^n}{n!}$ and showing that the sum of this series converges by the ratio test) and then conclude that because I can choose any $a \in \Bbb{R}_0^+$ for which the series converges uniformly, the radius of convergence is infinite (ie. I can choose an interval of any size for the M-test), or do I have to show that the series converges uniformly specifically on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is how we have defined the radius of convergence. I noticed when looking at this problem online that it seemed that our definition was different to the definition I was encountering online, however, this is how the lecturer defined it.

Comment: By that "definition", there are *no* power series with infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: How do you define _infinite_ radius of convergence in that case? Infinity isn't a (positive) real number.

Comment: I did not define it, the lecturer did, and no further definition was given regarding an infinite radius of convergence, however, this question was given asking us to prove an infinite radius of convergence for this series. I believe this is what has caused my confusion.

Comment: I can't blame you! You should contact your lecturer about this.

Comment: So, if, with the correct definition (just standard convergence?), is it the case that if the radius of convergence is infinite, what can we say about uniform convergence?

Comment: We can deduce that the convergence is uniform on every finite interval. However, the convergence isn't uniform on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Does the interval have to be closed? I looked up the definition and it said converges uniformly on every compact interval, so, isn't that closed and bounded in the context of the real numbers?

Comment: You can consider the supremum of the disk radii on which you have uniform convergence.

Comment: Also, would it be the case that my original proof showing that the ROC is infinite using the ratio test (ie. just showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n+1} = 0$) for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$ is correct? I don't need to introduce the Weierstrasse M-test?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $R = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}$, and $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n!}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) to calculate the radius of convergence.
$$ \frac{1}{r} = \limsup_{j \to \infty} |a_j|^{1/j}
$$
For Cauchy sequences, $\limsup$ can be replaced by $\lim$. Then, since the two following limits agree
$$ \lim_{j \to \infty} |a_j|^{1/j} = \lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{|a_{j+1}|}{a_j}
$$
Using the ratio test, it can be shown that $r^{-1} = 0$.